# Group by in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in Oracle:

```
ID            Start                  End        UNIT
AAAAA   20/08/1999 22:12    21/08/1999 00:50    Unit1
AAAAA   20/08/1999 23:40    21/08/1999 00:51    Unit2
BBBBB   20/08/1999 20:40    21/08/1999 00:53    Unit1
AAAAA   21/08/1999 00:51    21/08/1999 01:16    Unit1
AAAAA   21/08/1999 00:50    21/08/1999 01:20    Unit2
BBBBB   20/08/1999 21:42    22/08/1999 00:53    Unit1
```

I'm trying to have this output

```
    VALUE   TIMESTAMP            UNIT
    AAAAA   20/08/1999 22:12    Unit1
     0      21/08/1999 01:16    Unit1
    BBBBB   20/08/1999 20:40    Unit1
       0    22/08/1999 00:53    Unit1
    AAAAA   20/08/1999 23:40    Unit2
       0    21/08/1999 01:20    Unit2
```

ID goes with the FIRST occurrence of Start for each ID and 0 goes wit the LAST occurrence of End for each ID, individually separated by UNIT.

@Egor Skriptunoff and @Gordon Linoff helped me build a query for the first and last occurrence of ID, but I wonder what we have to do to group the results by UNIT.

Code that is already working not bringing the UNIT:

```
select VALUE, TIMESTAMP
from (
    select min(a.Start) TIMESTAMP,
           a.ID VALUE,
           a.ID,
           1 ORD
      from MyTable a
      group by a.ID

     union all 

    select max(a.End) TIMESTAMP,
           '0' VALUE,
           a.ID,
           2 ORD
      from MyTable a
      group by a.ID
)
order by ID, ORD
```

I'm trying to add the extra column UNIT that comes from the same table.

```
select VALUE, TIMESTAMP, UNIT
from (
    select min(a.Start) TIMESTAMP,
           a.ID VALUE,
           a.UNIT
           a.ID,
           1 ORD
      from MyTable a
      group by a.ID

     union all 

    select max(a.End) TIMESTAMP,
           '0' VALUE,
           a.ID,
           a.UNIT
           2 ORD
      from MyTable a
      group by a.ID
)
order by ID, ORD
```

but it's not working :(

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily add `unit` to my version:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then id else '0' end) as id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then start else "end" end) as timestamp,
       unit
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, unit order by start) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id, unit) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. I haven't used your version before before because I want to bring a value from another table depending on this unit value and I can't see how to do this in you example once I haven't completely understood it although it works perfectly, so that's my fault :(. Simply replacing unit for (select description from t2 where t2.unit = t.unit) is not working . What am I missing? Do I have to add t2 inside the original "from"?

Comment: @Dalek . . . I think you want to do a join from your table to the other table in the subquery.

Comment: I'm sorry Gordon, but I can't get it working... I tried "UNION all  select description from t2, t where t2.unit = t.unit" after your code but it's not compiling.

Comment: @Dalek . . . Maybe you should ask another question.  This question starts with `unit` as a filled column in the table.  I don't understand where it is coming from or why you would consider `union` for this.  I would expect `join`.